# User input by selection in excel spread sheet

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls

I am trying to find out if there is a method in VBA that would allow me to open a populated excel spread sheet and allow the user to select particular cells that contain data they want to extract in a whole series of files and then pass the selected cells back to the program so that it can loop through the 100s of files in the specified folder and extract the required data.

I'm not trying to have someone else write the code for me (though examples are awesome of course) I'm just not really sure how to go about the manual selection of the data and pass it back to the program. I already have the code functioning to extract the data sequentially through the 100s of files and put it where I need it in another sheet. I need manual selection because the location of the data in the files in each folder (user selected) can vary significantly. Right now I have to program in the locations of the data explicitly but we have 100s of report files with varying layouts within each one so manually programming in the locations of the data is extremely inefficient.

Ideas??

Comment: @me how - Please explain as I have reviewed the "how to ask" page and do not see where there is an issue. I asked a question that had an explanation of the issue I am facing and the direction I wish to proceed in with a rough outline of the inputs and outputs I desired. I did not include code as I am looking for a starting point for this particular issue and as such was not looking to have someone provide code for me but rather provide help with a direction to pursue based on greater experience than my own.

Comment: good answers below. Your bigger issue is going to be validating what the user has selected to make sure it meets the necessary criteria, and doing that before trying to run any other code. when you get to that point, that would be a good time to create another question and follow the "how to ask" guidelines. i.e. what have you tried, what code do you have, what are the rules you would like followed, the expected result, and where your code is having issues. **Welcome to SO!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with

```
Sub SelectRange()

    Dim selRng As Range
    Set selRng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Range", Title:="", Type:=8)

    MsgBox selRng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: that is surely a more compact solution. I appreciate the help with a direction to proceed.

Comment: +1. Like a `RefEdit` without the complicated overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RefEdit control on a UserForm. I think the RefEdit is not a default enabled control, so you may need to right-click the toolbox and enable it from the "Additional Controls", once you've done that, you should see it in the toolbox:

[image]

If you expect others to work with this macro, you may need to enable that on their machines or distribute the macro as part of an XLAM Add-In, otherwise it may not work for them.

[image]

The RefEdit control allows the user to select a range as input:

[image]

The control will have a name like `RefEdit1` (which you can change to something else in the VB  Properties pane of the VBE), and to access the passed value you would do like:

```
MsgBox UserForm2.RefEdit1.Value
```

Now that you have a handle on the selected range's `.Address`, you can pass it to other procedures/etc.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the direction! I'll try and post back what I come up with to help others in the future.

Comment: ++ but isn't this a bit overcomplicated?

Comment: ahhh yes @mehow I forget about the `InputBox` method. I don't do much in Excel anymore :)